# XUnit MethodName_Condition_Behaviour refactoring protection

Tags: c#, refactoring, xunit

In Unit Testing is common to use the convention:

```
MethodName_Condition_Behaviour()
```

Now, If for any reason I try to refactor the method "MethodName", I obtain inconsistent tests name for that method.

For handling this problem I thought this approach:

**Step 1**

Extend the XUnit Fact attribute and use a constructor that takes in input also the method to test name

```
public class FactForAttribute : FactAttribute
{
   public FactForAttribute(string methodName = "Constructor", [CallerMemberName] string testMethodName = "")
        => DisplayName = $"{methodName}_{testMethodName}";
}
```

**Step2**

Use the nameof operator to make refactoring possible:

```
public class A
{
    public int Just2() => 2;
}

public class ATests
{
    [FactFor(nameof(A.Just2))]
    public void Should_Return2()
    {
        var a = new A();
        a.Just2().Should().Be(2);
    }
}
```

Now the question. I never found this approach anywhere, so I doubt this is the best way to go.

There is any particular reason that make this approach not advisable?
There is any best practice to protect against refactoring using this convention?

Comment: Are you testing every class/method in your project or only publicly exposed "contract"?

Comment: Every Public method/prop/event with some business logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For readability reasons.*

Coders want to see exactly what unit test is being talked about on first sight without having to do the tracking. Espacially since this implementation adds little maintainability value.

(But to be fair, I'd be exactly the type of programmer to do this if allowed :D)

Comment: I see your point. Makes sense. But personally I think consistency is more important (that's only a opinion of course). Also, the test name should appear the same way in the tests recap. So is only slightly less readable while watching the code

Comment: Yes, you are perfectly right about that. And as said, I'd do it too if I was allowed to at my workplace. If "Just2" was for example renamed later on, all of the unit tests, testing it wouldn't have to be renamed as well. But it's the generally accepted standard across developers not to do so because readability takes the highest priority for most programmers.